# In Django Polls Tutorial: Getting "NameError: name 'Question' is not defined"

Tags: django-models

SOLVED: I need to import the objects in the shell.

```
>>> from polls.models import Choice, Question  # Import the model classes we just wrote.
```

---

Running the command `Question.objects.all()` returns the error `NameError: name 'Question' is not defined.`

My polls/models.py looks like this:

---

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

---

What's puzzling is that I ran the shell for the first snippet of this tutorial and **had no problem**. I was able to create a Question object and query it and do all the expected things. I made some edits to models.py (adding timezone and **str** (since commented out and here removed)) and now can't get Question class recognized at all.

What's going on?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

> > > from polls.models import Choice, Question  # Import the model classes we just wrote.